# I have an issue with np.maximum.outer: NotImplementedError. Is there a way around? (This works well in Python 2.7)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a matrix like this:

```
RCA = pd.DataFrame(
  data=[
    (1,0,0,0),
    (1,1,1,0),
    (0,0,1,0),
    (0,1,0,1),
    (1,0,1,0)],
    columns=['ct1','ct2','ct3','ct4'],
    index=['ind_1','ind_2','ind_3','ind_4','ind_5'])
```

I´m trying to calculate:

```
norms = RCA.sum()
norm = np.maximum.outer(norms, norms)
proximity = RCA.T.dot(RCA).div(norm)
```

However, when I run this part: `norm = np.maximum.outer(norms, norms)`

I´m getting this error:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2aa7f9ca5eb8> in <module>
      4 
      5 norms = RCA.sum()
----> 6 norm = np.maximum.outer(norms, norms)
      7 proximity = RCA.T.dot(RCA).div(norm)
      8 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    746             return None
    747         else:
--> 748             return construct_return(result)
    749 
    750     def __array__(self, dtype=None) -> np.ndarray:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in construct_return(result)
    735                 if method == "outer":
    736                     # GH#27198
--> 737                     raise NotImplementedError
    738                 return result
    739             return self._constructor(result, index=index, name=name, copy=False)

NotImplementedError:
```

Does anybody know what´s going on and how can I perform the same task in an alternative way?

Comment: Try `np.maximum.outer(norms.to_numpy(), norms.to_numpy())`.  It works fine on a numpy array.  But for some reason, `pandas` does not implement it for Series.  You could  look up the `GH#27198` issue on the pandas github site.  Sometimes `numpy` functions convert inputs like Series to arrays and do the job, other times they delegate some level of detail to the Series.

Comment: Looks like all `ufunc` `outer` has been removed.  `outer` on a pair of 1d arrays returns a 2d array.  A Series is 1d, but what should an `outer` on Series return?  Array?  dataframe?   https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27186